# PNG file opening with alpha channel

Tags: png

I have to edit image provided by my client. 
The problem is that when I open it with Adobe Photoshop, Gimp or Corel Draw it opens wrong. Image itself seems to use alpha channel, but I cant see it in photoshop. Instead of thatshadows looks very poor and when I save it the problem remains.
Please, take a look on the image and photoshop screenshot. Please tell me tools or tricks I should try (windows or linux) to open it correctly, edit and save it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a bug in Photoshop that has been fixed in CS6.

You've got [PNG-8 with alpha](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2010/png-that-works/#8bit+alpha), which Photoshop CS5 can't read, an no version can write it.

To work around this open the file in an application that fully supports PNG (on Mac it can be Preview.app) and re-save it.

Comment: What about the others? Gimp should be unaffected by a CS bug.

Comment: I haven't tested GIMP, but it might have PNG support lacking as well.